# Variable scope in plugin outside loop

Tags: plugins, hooks

OK so I'm trying to use the plugin "adrotate" outside of the loop for my frontend.

I can access all the WP functions I need for everything else using

```
require_once(APP_PATH.BLOG_FOLDER.'wp-load.php');
```

The plugin has a function called `adrotate_group()` which is just in a script file, no class or anything.

```
function adrotate_group($group_ids, $fallback = 0, $weight = 0) {
    global $wpdb, $adrotate_config, $adrotate_debug;
    var_dump($adrotate_config);
```

This outputs `NULL` when I call it like so on my frontend

```
require_once(APP_PATH.BLOG_FOLDER.'wp-load.php');
echo adrotate_group(1);
```

`$adrotate_config` is setup in another setup script for this plugin and I've done some var_dumps there and it outputs to my frontend correctly.

Below is where the variable is set

[image]

For some reason using `global $adrotate_config` in that function isn't working, however using `get_option('adrotate_config');` does, but I cannot go edit all of the plugin functions to use this as it will break on updates.

I think it has to do with the way I'm hooking wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK FIXED using

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once(APP_PATH.BLOG_FOLDER.'wp-blog-header.php');
```

instead of wp-load.php